# get validated data in custom laravel 5.2 validation rule

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

i'm trying to add a validation rule for composite unique in laravel 5.2. every thing worked fine.

```
'student_id' => 'unique_com:marks,exam_id,' . $data['exam_id']
```

but when i use it on array data i don't know how to pass the `$data['exam_id']`

```
'mark.*.student_id' => 'unique_com:marks,exam_id,(what i can pass here)'
```

or is there a way to access the validated data inside the extended validation rule.

note: `exam_id` is the name of the second column in the database table `marks,student_id and exam_id should be composite unique`.

Comment: Do you have the array of exam_ids?

Comment: yes i do like this  data[mark][0][student_id] ,data[mark][0][exam_id]

Comment: I do not understand why you can not just concatenate as above?
Are you looking for like 'unique_com:marks,exam_id|unique_com:marks,student_id'?

Comment: Because I have an array of mark I can only content one item

Answer (score 0):

You can put your validation in a variable first, then iterate in each exam_ids

```
$validation_rules = [];

$i = 0;
foreach ($exam_ids as $exam_id) {
    $validation_rules['mark.'.$i.'.student_id'] = 'unique_com:marks,exam_id,' . $exam_id;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: is there more efficient why